# Set max value in Y BarChart ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, charts, bar-chart

I want to set the Y values from 0 to 100 jumping 10 by 10. I can't find any docs, property or a related post about how to set it up. I would appreciate any help.
I'm using aspx and aspx.vb as the backend file. 
 **aspx file**

```
<asp:BarChart
    ID="BarChart1"
    runat="server"
    ChartHeight="300"
    ChartWidth="1200"
    ChartType="Column"
    ChartTitleColor="#0095AA"
    CategoryAxisLineColor="#99A7B7"
    ValueAxisLineColor="#99A7B7"
    BaseLineColor="#666666"
    CssClass="nolegend noborder">
</asp:BarChart>
```

**aspx.vb function**

```
Private Sub fillGraph()
    Dim dtFacultad = getFacultad()
    Dim total = dtFacultad.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim x As String() = data
    Dim y As Decimal() = New Decimal(total) {}

    For i As Integer = 0 To total
        y(i) = i * 10 'Dummy data'
    Next

    BarChart1.Series.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries() With {
        .Data = y
    })
    BarChart1.CategoriesAxis = String.Join(",", x)
    BarChart1.ChartWidth = (x.Length * 125).ToString()
End Sub
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: From [www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-control-toolkit-tutorial-barchart-part-ten/](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-control-toolkit-tutorial-barchart-part-ten/), it looks like setting `ValueAxisLines="9"` might work.

Comment: Or "8", or "10" maybe.

Comment: @Andrew Morton it changes the Y values but it doesn't get to 100. Anyways thanks for the information, didn't knew that.

Comment: The [System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting?view=netframework-4.8) could give you much more flexibility. There are examples available if you search for them.

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
BarChart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 10 ' Interval from 10 to 10
BarChart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = 100 ' Y axis maximum = 100
```

With this you'll have interval from 10 to 10 in Y axis and also the maximum value in Y axis will be 100.

Comment: I saw that in previous blogs but the property "ChartAreas" doesn't exists in my BarChart1. Is that normal?

Comment: Are you using an object of type "Chart"?

Comment: No, the object is "AjaxControlToolKit.BarChart".